# Машина Тьюринга

Tags: алгоритм, системы-счисления

Помогите решить задачу:
A={0,1} Входное слово — корректная запись двоичного числа.
Перевести его в четверичную систему счисления.

**Обновление**

Я плохо представляю себе, как осуществить перевод чисел из двоичной системы счисления в четверичную с помощью МТ.

Comment: @mango44, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришлось сделать таблицу соответствия десятичных (аж до 45) чисел к двоичным и к четверичным.

Смотри:

```
Десятичные    Двоичные    Четверичные
   2             10           2
   3             11           3
   10           1010          22
   15           1111          33
   26          11010         122
   31          11111         133
```

Видите закономерность? Осталось только сделать алгоритм для машины Тьюринга, на пальцах его очень сложно обьяснить, поэтому я воспользовался Эмулятором этой машины, который вот [тут](http://cmcmsu.no-ip.info/1course/alg.schema.mt.htm#).

А сам код (или схема) для нее вот, вставьте в поле "схема МТ":

```
      0      1     _
0    ,R,    ,R,   ,L,1
1   _,L,2  _,L,3  1,N,!
2   0,L,4  2,L,4  1,N,!
3   1,L,4  3,L,4  ,N,!
4   ,N,1  ,N,1  ,N,!
```

Эмулятор чуть глюченый, перед вводом нового числа всегда нажимайте "сброс на начало" и вводите заново двоичное число. Между числами есть пробелы, но ты можешь от них избавиться сам, я верю :).

Удачки, могут быть баги - я хз.